# Filter rows over partitions

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Suppose I have the following table:

```
    +-------+------------+
    | nGroup |   Status   |
    +-------+------------+
    |     1 | DONE       |
    |     1 | UNKNOWN    |
    |     1 | DONE       |
    |     2 | INPROGRESS |
    |     2 | INPROGRESS |
    |     2 | DONE       |
    |     3 | INPROGRESS |
    |     3 | DONE       |
    |     3 | DONE       |
    +-------+------------+
```

If a *nGroup* has one *Status* to **INPROGRESS**, then return only the lines of that group containing the status **INPROGRESS**.

If all the *Status* of a *nGroup* are different from **INPROGRESS**, then return all the status available for that group.

So for this example, I would get the following output:

```
+-------+------------+
| nGroup |   Status   |
+-------+------------+
|     1 | DONE       |
|     1 | UNKNOWN    |
|     1 | DONE       |
|     2 | INPROGRESS |
|     2 | INPROGRESS |
|     3 | INPROGRESS |
+-------+------------+
```

I tried the following query :

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.myTable T1 
WHERE Status IN (
  CASE WHEN EXISTS( SELECT 1 FROM myTable T2 WHERE T2.STATUS = 'INPROGRESS' AND T1.nGroup = T2.nGroup) THEN 'INPROGRESS'
  ELSE (SELECT Status FROM myTable T2 WHERE T1.nGroup = T2.nGroup) 
  END
)
```

But I get the following error when running it :

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the
>   subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as
>   an expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will do it:

```
select m.*
from myTable m
where 
  m.Status = 'INPROGRESS' 
  OR NOT EXISTS (
    select 1 from myTable where nGroup = m.nGroup and Status = 'INPROGRESS'
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm . . . I think you want:

```
select t.*
from dbo.myTable t
where t.status <> 'INPROGRESS' or
      exists (select 1
              from dbo.myTable t
              where db.myTable = 'INPROGRESS'
             );
```